# query is not executed in vbulletin php

Tags: php, sql, vbulletin

I am writing a plugin for vbulletin, which includes creating a new thread - the query below is what I have done. The query runs perfectly in phpmyadmin, but is not executed when ran within the php file; no error was reported. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `thread` (`threadid`,  `title`,    `prefixid`, `firstpostid`,  `lastpostid`,   `lastpost`, `forumid`,  `pollid`,   `open`, `replycount`,   `hiddencount`,  `deletedcount`, `postusername`, `postuserid`,   `lastposter`,   `dateline`, `views`,    `iconid`,   `notes`,    `visible`,  `sticky`,   `votenum`,  `votetotal`,    `attach`,   `similar`,  `taglist`,  `awardedcredits`,   `threaddesc`)
                    VALUES        (NULL,        '$mname',    '',         '0',            '0',            '0',        '$M4rumid', '0',         '1',    '0',            '0',            '0',            '$username',     '$userid',       '$username',     '$date',     '0',        '0',        '',         '1',        '0',        '0',        '0',            '0',        '',         NULL,       '0',                'awarded');
             SET    @threadid = LAST_INSERT_ID();

             INSERT INTO `post`   (`postid`,    `threadid`, `parentid`, `username`,     `userid`,   `title`,    `dateline`,     `pagetext`,     `allowsmilie`,  `showsignature`,    `ipaddress`,    `iconid`,   `visible`,  `attach`,   `infraction`,   `reportthreadid`,   `kbank`,    `post_thanks_amount`)
                    VALUES        (NULL,        @threadid,  '0',        '$username',    '$userid',  '$mname',   '$date',        '$postcontent', '1',            '1',                '',             '0',        '1',        '0',        '0',            '0',                '0.00',     '0');
             SET    @postid = LAST_INSERT_ID();

             UPDATE `thread` 
             SET    `firstpostid` = @postid,
                    `lastpostid` = @postid,
                    `lastpost` = '$date'
             WHERE  `threadid` = @threadid;

             UPDATE `user` 
             SET    `posts` = `posts`+1
             WHERE  `userid` = '$userid';");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are 4 queries and not 1.

From The [PHP Manual on mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) :

> mysql_query() sends a **unique query (multiple queries are not supported)** to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

And by the way, on the same page:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

And by the way here is how VBulletin wants you to interact with its database: [**Vbulletin SQL query syntax**](http://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/main/codestandards_sql_query).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that ._. is there anyway to run multiple queries?

Comment: Yes, with **mysqli_multi_query** as suggested by sgeddes, but you should stick with vBulletin syntax.

Comment: Thank you, one more question, is there any problem if I keep using mysql_query()?

Comment: Your code will be unusable in the future, when the function is removed from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is you can't run multiple queries with mysql_query.  Check this link out:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

And from their site:

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not
>   supported) to the currently active database on the server that's
>   associated with the specified link_identifier.

Try using mysqli_multi_query instead:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it's more complicate than I thought, I guess I have to split it into 4 single mysql_query...